# Getting data from past month, past year, etc

Tags: android, mysql

I want to be able to display different data depending on what the user chooses to display. There will be four options, past week, past month, past year, and all. This is in a spinner, and I want this format.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    switch(pos)
    {
        case 0:
            pastMonthSelected();
            break;
         case 1:
             pastYearSelected(); 
             break;

          ... etc. 

    }


}


public void pastMonthSelected(){
       \\code
}
public void pastYearSelected(){
       \\code
}

 etc...
}
```

I have a database that has stored the date in the format MM/DD/YY as a full string, along with two other strings (time and description). I am really new to databases, and I don't understand how to start this. I know that I need to create a query

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');
```

from previous threads that I looked through. 
but I'm not sure where I should put this. I think I also need to create some sort of table first, but I'm really confused right now.

My Database class has these variables right now

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "music";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "practices";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
public static final String KEY_DES = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
```

and I have an onCreate method, onUpgrade, methods to delete someting, add something, and retrieve everything. Some help on how and where I should add stuff to this class would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: First, fix your database to store dates as *date*, not as a string.  Using the proper types will simplify your life, in most cases.

Comment: How do I do that? I have a DatePicker, but then it is set so that when the user chooses a date, it is displayed in the EditText field as MM/DD/YY. I have been just using that format from the EditText.